# retriving web.config appsettings on html page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wanna use appsettings value from web.config file on html page in javascript or jquery. The content from my web.config file is:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings> 
   <add key="ServiceURL" value="http://localhost:16917/Service1.svc"></add>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have tried with

```
var serviceUrl='<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"].ToString() %>'
alert(serviceUrl);
```

Instead of showing value from webconfig it is showing  `<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"].ToString() %>` on alert.

Can anybody help me please.

Comment: It seems you have inserted server side code into a pure html page. That is not possible. The code between the brackets are not executed. Check your server configuration.

Comment: is dr any other way to do so........ or what configuration I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing closing tag '>'

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings> 
   <add key="ServiceURL" value="http://localhost:16917/Service1.svc"> </add>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Alright. then you should write that javascript on asp.net web form. html won't understand your server code

Answer (score 0):

1. Change WebConfig UI

`<pages pageBaseType="Main.Web.ViewPage">`

2. Create an abstract class that implement from the WebViewPage.

> ```
> public abstract class ViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
>     {
>         public ViewPage()
>         {
>         }
>
>         public JSSettings UISession
>         {
>             get
>             {
>                 var appSettingsFileBasedSettings = new JSSettings()
>                 {
>                     SessionTimeoutMinutes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeoutMinutes"]
>                 };
>                 return appSettingsFileBasedSettings;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

3. In the html page just do something like.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>         var show = {
>             Settings : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.UISession))
>             };
>
>         console.log(show);
> </script>
> ```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var test = {
    ServiceURL: <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"] %>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with static HTML file, at least not in any good way.

Instead, use the power of ASP.NET and work with a Web Form, where you have Code Behind.

In the code behind, send the value from the server to the client as JS variable:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "ServiceURL_JS", 
        string.Format("var serviceUrl = \"{0}\"; ", 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"]), true
    );
}
```

Now you can access the variable `serviceUrl` in the client side JS.